# Why is site faster without Full Page Cache on?

Tags: cache, full-page-cache, enterprise-1.13, redis

We recently had to do a code deployment to a server cluster. We turn off cache before the deployment. We forgot to turn the cache back on but then after looking at NewRelic we noticed the response time of the site is faster without FPC?
[image]

Can anyone think of a reason? We are using Object Rocket from Rackspace for the caching.

Comment: Any chance your website is completely over https?

Comment: No it is not on https :(

Answer (score 1):

If your website is delivered completely over https then full page cache will not be enabled but when you turn full page cache on it will also disable the normal block cache essentially turning off all caching. But when you turn full page cache off then block cache will be back on.

I think this issue is fixed in 1.14

Answer (score 0):

Maybe partial caching was still on. Therefore, the performance increase was due to the fact that part of your pages were being rendered new if they needed to be (CPU LOAD). But other users would still get their pages from the cache. I heard Magento has a lot of performance issues when it comes to caching.